# PHPUnit coverage in Cobertura format

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, cobertura

I have a small PHP project that uses PHPUnit for unit tests and coverage. I would like to generate the coverage reports in cobertura XML format.

Is there any tool or plugin that I can use to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Have you ever resolved this problem? I would like to generate a coverage report in Cobertura XML format but i didn't find any existing solution.

Comment: No its been a while, and I havent taken a look at it.

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: Maybe this plugin could help you https://github.com/Soyhuce/phpunit-to-cobertura

Answer (score 26):

Support for Cobertura format has just been merged to phpunit and phpcov, and it is available in phpunit 9.4

The report can be generated by invoking phpunit with this flag:

```
phpunit --coverage-cobertura=my-cobertura-coverage.xml
```

Comment: related PR: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/pull/812

Answer (score 4):

You can configure **cobertura** support in config file `phpunit.xml`.

Here an example, put the following code inside `<phpunit/>` tag:

```
  <coverage cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache/code-coverage"
            processUncoveredFiles="true">
    <include>
      <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
    </include>
    <report>
      <cobertura outputFile="cobertura.xml"/>
      <html outputDirectory="phpunit-html"/>
      <text outputFile="php://stdout"/>
    </report>
  </coverage>
```

Note the `<cobertura/>` tag in the example.

Answer (score -3):

The XML format for code coverage information logging produced by PHPUnit is loosely based upon the one used by Clover.